# Colocar 4 colunas em um linha

Tags: html

A questão é a seguinte, sou extremamente newbie em `html/css` e estou modificando um tema do `wordpress`.

O tema funciona a partir de colunas, e eu preciso de ajuda especificamente nisso.[image: .]

Como podem ver, são "caixas" de serviço, essas caixas não parecem ter largura definida, ou seja, a largura delas é definida pela largura da coluna em que estão inseridas.

Na foto, são 3 caixas, inseridas em uma coluna de `30.66% de width`, até aí perfeito.

Mas eu preciso de colocar mais 4 em baixo, exatamente da mesma largura que estas, o problema é que quando eu coloco a quarta, ela quebra a linha e vai pra linha de baixo, como mostra na segunda print
[image: segunda foto]

Eu quero conseguir colocar 4 caixas dessas em apenas uma linha, como posso fazer isso? Alguma orientação?

Comment: Coloque algum código para ajudar os membros entenderem o seu problema.

Comment: Você já tentou diminuir a largura delas para um valor menor que 25%?

Comment: Oi, Diogo.Sim, eu alterei isso, mas como disse, eu queria que eles se mantivessem na mesma largura da linha de cima, ou seja, 30.66%. Eu quero as divs das colunas não quebrem a linha quando chegarem na quarta, por exemplo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apenas uma atualização, sobre como consegui resolver.

Meu problema era o seguinte, eu queria criar uma div que fosse mais larga que sua div-pai, pra dessa forma alinhar as caixas de dentro em full width, sem que quebrassem a linha ao chegar na widht máxima da div-pai

```
.filhofw {
position: relative;
width: 100vw;
left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
```

Depois só deixei a largura das caixas em px e alinhei tudo, coloquei elas dentro do filho (full width)